# Jackson time-zone property in Spring Boot application.yaml works in IDE but not in docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, jackson, openshift

Ok, full disclosure first. I am working on a project that uses java.util.Date on it's entity and dto objects and we are working to change to LocalDateTime. We are naturally having timezone issues when Jackson serializes our dto objects to JSON at the controller layer. We are working to change the Date to LocalDateTime, but in the interim, setting the following property:

```
  jackson:
    time-zone: Canada/Pacific
```

works to convert the date/time to the correct value. However, our application is deployed as a docker container hosted on Openshift. Once in docker, even on my local machine, I can change this value to anything and the date never changes. I have tried checking the TZ value in the linux container and it matches our timezone, etc. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Use [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), not [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). No issue with time zone.

## Use `Instant`, not `LocalDateTime`

> uses java.util.Date on it's entity and dto objects and we are working to change to LocalDateTime

`LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use here. That class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Therefore, objects of that class cannot represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. With just a date and a time-of-day, we have know way to know if you mean that time in Tokyo, Toulouse, or Toledo, for example — three very different moments several hours apart.

The class replacing `java.util.Date` is [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). Both represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline, as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC.

So **use `Instant`**. Your time zone issue goes away entirely.

## ISO 8601

When serializing textually to JSON, XML, etc., use only standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. For a moment in UTC, that would like this: `2023-04-28T19:31:41.078125Z`. The `Z` on the end is an abbreviation of `+00:00`, an offset of zero; pronounced “Zulu”.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text. No need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String output = myInstant.toString() ;
```

… and:

```
Instant myInstant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

## Applying a time zone

To view that moment through the wall-clock time of a particular time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Vancouver" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = myInstant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same moment as the `Instant` object, but different wall-clock time & possibly different date.
```

In this code, both `myInstant` and `zdt` represent the very same moment, the same simultaneous point on the timeline. Like two people calling each other in Vancouver BC and Reykjavík [Iceland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Iceland), if both persons simultaneously look up at the calendar and clock on their respective walls, they will see a different time of day and possibly a different date.

## Avoid default zone

> We are naturally having timezone issues when Jackson serializes our dto

You are **unnecessarily introducing time zone** where it is not needed.

Notice how **none of the code above depends on a default** time zone. Write your code to avoid implicitly depending on the JVM’s current default time zone. Always pass the optional time zone argument.